# Java Maven project creating failed in ecilipse

Tags: java, maven

when I am creating new maven project in eclipse, it failed to create project.
its about dependencies.. I am uploading screen shot
I am creating project with jar packaging.

[image: this a screen shot( Blue circle )]

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do these steps:
1: Delete .M2 Content 2

3: Close Eclipse..and reopen

4: clean and update project configuration

5: verify the java buld path used for the project configuration

6: Try use the Maven embedded in eclipse just for a test, to see if the problem is the external Maven installation corrupted

Comment: I don't know but after doing these steps, it is fine now.. can you elaborate, what actually  happen?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have declared your maven resource plugin correctly in your pom.xml and also post your pom.xml for other users to see.

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: here is my pom.xml file
'<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>pk.ciit.testApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>pk.ciit.testApp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>testApp</name>
  <description>making this for testing app
makin</description>
</project>
'

Comment: I think you are missing a lot of things in your pom. It is very much empty with no dependencies declared. I suggest you read more about maven project setup at the following link https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: It is fixed now,,, by following @Abdelhak answer's step.. 
anyhow thank you so much.